# Laravel Link button to function

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to call a function the creates random codes with a button, but somehow i always get this error "Route [generateKitID] not defined", even though my route is defined. Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

kitprep.blade.php:

```
  <tr>
    {{csrf_field()}}
      <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary"><a href="{{route('generateKitID')}}">KitID</a></button></td>
    <td>
      @if(isset($char_KitID))
       {{$char_KitID}}
     @else not default
      @endif
     </td>
  </tr>
```

HomeController.php:

```
public function generateKitID()
{
    //Generate random KitID, length 6, no o!
    $char_KitID = substr(str_shuffle("0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, 6);
    return view("kitprep", compact($char_KitID));
}
```

web.php:

```
// Generate random codes
Route::get('/kitprep', 'HomeController@generateKitID')->name('generateKitID');
```

Comment: {{ URL::route('generateKitID') }}

Comment: already tried that, but i still get the same error

Comment: weird, have you tried removing the capitals and leading slash from the route name. changing it to something like:
Route::get('kitprep', 'HomeController@generateKitID')->name('kitid.generate');

{{ route('kitid.generate') }}

Comment: yes, i already tried that

Answer (score 0):

Hey could you try this:

> {{ URL::route('generateKitID') }}

Also please make sure your name is correct (might be a spelling error in one of them)

Comment: thanks for your quick reply!. I tried your suggestion, but I still get the same error, also checked the spelling and everything is correct.

Comment: @matilarab do you mind trying to change your web route to POST instead of get? I had the same problem my self I just don't recall how I solved it.

Comment: Exactly, I was about to say the same thing, try changing your route from get to post.